# What Immigration status do I have in Canada when on International Internship Programme (VIE)

Tags: eu-citizens, working-visas, canada

There is this VIE program, so-called [International Internship Programme](https://www.civiweb.com/international/EN/index.aspx).

The principle is to work abroad, and it applies to many European citizens. The work contract is a bit specific.

I am wondering what is the immigration status of such a contract when doing it in Canada. Is it a simple work permit?

I am particularly worried if there is any impact on a possible future application to the [IEC (International Experience in Canada)](http://www.international.gc.ca/experience/index.aspx): will I be allowed to participate to both programs?

As a bonus. I would like to know if it has any (positive or negative) impact on a future permanent residence application?

Answer (score 2):

The best I can figure the VIE is a program where you get an internship with a French company and then that company transfers you abroad to learn how business works over on the other side.

So if that is the case you will be either an [intra-company transfer](http://www.canadaworkvisa.ca/info/ict.php) or more likely a [Business Visitor](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/visit/business.asp).  In the first case the company that you're working for will have to give you a Work Permit in Canada for which the duration could be up to 7 years but in the second case you will need get a [Temporary Resident Visa](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/information/applications/visa.asp).

I would think that the best way to determine this would be to contact [Ubifrance](http://www.ubifrance.com) which administers this program.